# How to add vimeo player into pop up window when it clck on Image..???

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add video into my website. But I want to play that video within pop up window when user click on image. How can I do that.??

I want to create that look like this website.
https://www.shoplocket.com/

Thanxx :)

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you should know what kind of popup you want. Just a new screen or a nice effect like the website you provided.

In the last case you could look at some popular popup possibilities like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/),... 
Depending on the plugin you choose, you'll have to check their documentation to embed video's.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use colorbox

see [here for example](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/).

Check out the Vimeo Content in it.

> To open Vimeo content with it simply:
>
> 1. Create a link (<a href="#"></a>).
> 2. Add the rel attribute “prettyPhoto” to it (rel=”prettyPhoto”).
> 3. Change the href of your link so it points to the Vimeo video page, the same link you would share with friends.

Code:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqXi8WmQ_WM" rel="prettyPhoto" title=""><img src="images/thumbnails/flash-logo.jpg" alt="YouTube" width="60" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To play a video put it as content of a popup

```
<video id="videoPop" class="video" controls >
    <source src="adress">
</video>
```

This is popup itself:
HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
  function myFunction() {
   var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
   popup.classList.toggle('show');
  }
</script>
```

When I write this the website you mentioned does not work, so I live CSS for you.

No you need HTML trigger:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```